Image seems to render, but as soon as it is done, the image becomes completely transparent
When rendering this image of a covered wagon below, it goes through the tiles seemingly normally, but after completing all tiles, the image is completely transparent, the rendered parts vanish, so to speak.
The world object has a hdri applied, but its on transparent, which is what I want.
I know there has been a very old post with the same question, but then the problem was that no camera was chosen as active camera. That is not the problem here, I believe.
I guess this has something to do with too little vram. I suspect that because very small images have rendered successfully, but larger ones have this problem. I have reduced the tile size (down to 255) because it says that should save on memory. But the tilesize doesnt seem to affect it.
I have tried rendering on the CPU, but then an Error appears about "not being able to write tile to file". (second image)



hello, are you using the Compositor?

Hello, I have unchecked 'use nodes' . So I guess that means No. I havent used the compositor really ever before, but i hope that answers it.

Check that  your file path is correct

Yes, the path at Properties/Output is a valid path, I have changed it to a different drive, but that doesn't help it.

Which version of Blender are you using? This "error writing tile to file" some people had in the past with older Blender versions when either the temp directory for intermediate results could not be created or not accessed due to not having writing permissions or when you set a custom path for the temp folder in the preferences which could not be created or accessed. Try to look in the system console (menu Window > Toggle System Console) what the error exactly says. Try running Blender as administrator if this helps.

Adding to Gondon's hints, check if you don't have an original open image in another software (can't overwrite a file that is being used)

Im using 4.1.1. Even without starting the render, just after opening the file,
it puts out the following (i cut it a little):
...
WARN (bke.appdir): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v410\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\appdir.cc:1163 tempdir_session_create: Could not generate a temp file name for...
It tries to save a temporary autosave file to some directory from the blender installation. Im guessing Blender might always temporarily save rendered files to such a folder. And only if it has to render several images,
it uses the folder specified in Properties/Output.

I have now tried to run and render as admin, and it worked. So it actually is a problem with blender not having permission to write there. Can you give a particular programm write acess to a drive? I have seen that I could give the standard user access to the c-drive, but thats probably not good.
Either way, thank you guys very much for helping!

I would checkmark your comment, Gordon Brinkmann, as an answer, if you want to turn your comment into a full answer, so I can accept it.
